# PHP storing password in cookie

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a relatively secure way to store the password in the browser cookie (for remembering the login information) in the cookie without creating an extra column for hash in database?
Thanks.

Comment: so if the cookie gets deleted, they lose their ability to authenticate?

Comment: hm, database would be better, but if you do it like adam said it´s tolerable...

Comment: @Shango - Why would that happen?

Comment: The cookie will also have to be sent over https, otherwise someone could just authenticate with a replay attack

Comment: @Shango: If a user wish to remember his password, then i suppose i should store it in the cookie. of course if the cookie is deleted, the user would  need to login again.

Comment: Storing passwords in session is nevertheless better than cookie. Besides, you save on bandwidth (storing in session does not require to send all information in the session, storing in cookie sends the data back and forth the server). No matter how secure your password is on the cookie, it can be cracked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store a salted hash of the password in the cookie

```
$salt = 'snfcikkfbnvekrew';
$cookie_value = md5($salt . $password);
```

Comment: and maybe hash the salted password twice or more times.

Comment: And use a user-specific salt - although that would require another column in the db

Comment: I wouldn't say it's secure though ... granted, you won't be able to find out the password, but if someone gets their hands on the cookie, they're in through the door.  Session IDs at least are context sensitive, time out, are made redundant ... this could last in perpetuity.

Comment: @#user-specific-salt: Not if you use the userid or his email address (usually people need to enter their password when changing the email address so updating the password hash would not be a problem in this case)

Comment: MD5 is no longer secure. Use SHA-256 instead

Comment: Or at least sha1 if you don't want to rely on mhash being available.

Answer (score 10):

You should ***never ever*** store plaintext or even decryptable passwords in your database unless ***you*** have generated them and the user **cannot** enter a custom one!

The most common way is storing the hash of the password in the cookie which is also in the database. However, this allows anyone to login by just knowing the hash - without access to the original password. So don't go by that way even though it's obviously the easiest one.

A secure approach would be storing a random, unique "login hash" in the database and setting this hash plus the user's ID in the cookie. That would not only make the password hash useless for logging in but also allow you to create a "log out everywhere" feature.

Comment: As I said, it's the most common way but discouraged.

Comment: The other common way is just using a session cookie. This provides enough indirection as it's a random unique hash by itself.

Comment: That's seldom used for "stay logged in"-like functionality though.

Answer (score 2):

Storing the password, or a representation of the password in a cookie is a very bad idea.  Granted, you can protect the cookie so that reading the password isn't possible, but if the cookie is intercepted, someone else can set that cookie, giving them the full permissions of the previous user up until the point that that password is changed.

With direct machine access, it would be possible to steal the cookie even if HTTPS were used, and then steal a person's full access even without knowing the password value, again, until they change that password.

It may be possible to do it securely via some obscure method of time specific hashing, but my recommendation is not to do it at all.  Use sessions instead, and try to store an internal identifier rather than an external one.  If a session is compromised, the consequences are still serious, but generally less so as the session will expire, and sessions lend themselves well to other forms of security (IP lockdown, request sequencing, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: never store passwords in cookies or- if unsalted- anywhere. Don't. In your scenario [JSON web tokens (JWT)](https://jwt.io) could be used to store authorization on client side.